# How to find the content of selected cell in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, radgridview

I am trying to get the selected cells and their contents in GridView while copying. While copying a cell's content I get cell item source instead of cell content.

Event for copying the grid

```
private void RadGrid_CopyingCellClipboardContent(object sender, GridViewCellClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
      var textBlock = e.Cell as TextBlock;

      if (textBlock != null)
      {
        e.Value = textBlock.Text;
      }
    }
```

I always get textblock as null. How can I get the cell content while copying.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily need to use the RadGrid_CopyingCellClipboardContent event, you may want to use the SelectedIndexChanged event, instead. You can use this event to determine when a cell has been selected, and then use the SelectedRow property to access the individual cells and text that you need.

To see some of this in action, check out the MSDN page on the GridView.SelectedIndexChanged event here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with DataGridTextColumn, you should use:

```
TextBlock textBlock = e.Cell.Content as TextBlock;
```

also, you should know that if a cell is in editing mode, then the content is a TextBox, not a TextBlock.